# youtube vudeos inside fancybox iframe popup with fullscreen mode

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, fancybox, fullscreen

I am having an issue with youtube fullscrenn mode when it's inside an iframe fancybox popup.
I am using wordpress + [easy fancybox plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/)

I have homepage and special page called "videos" which shows when clicking on a button in the homepage which opens an iframe popup and displaying hte "videos" page inside that iframe.

it works fine but it disables the "fullscreen" option
[image]

when I oprn the page regularly from within the wordpress admin in a separate browsers it works just fine.
[image]

I understand it happens because I am trying to open it from within an iframe.
is there any solution to that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy fancybox plugin uses fancybox v1.3.4 and the *fullscreen* option is disabled because the (fancybox) iframe doesn't have the `allowfullscreen` attribute.

You may need to add it using the `onComplete` callback like:

```
onComplete : function () {
    $("#fancybox-frame").attr("allowfullscreen", "allowfullscreen")
}
```

You may need to ask the plugin's author how to do that
https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/easy-fancybox

I am assuming you are calling your video using the URL `embed` format like:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/SvKmSNxFHyQ">open youtube iframe</a>
```

and setting fancybox `type` as `iframe`

See **[DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/youtubeFullScreen_06Jan16.html)** with fullscreen enabled/disabled with this method.